# How to create a rollover button in swing

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, rollover

So I have two buttons,

```
JButton playB = new JButton(new ImageIcon("res/playA.png"));
playB.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
playB.setContentAreaFilled(false);
JButton playA = new JButton(new ImageIcon("res/playA.png"));
playA.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
playA.setContentAreaFilled(false);
```

How would I create it so that when I move my mouse over button A it switches to button B? All I can think of doing is using a mouse listener but I'm wondering if there would be any better way.

Comment: What is your purpose of that switch? JButtons are very modal and you can do anything with it depending on the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How would I create it so that when I move my mouse over button A it
>   switches to button B? All I can think of doing is using a mouse
>   listener but I'm wondering if there would be any better way.
>
> Note: The setRolloverIcon method can't be used for this.

- this idea, switching with two [JButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)s isn't ..., nor to use [MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html), because all mouse and key events are implemented in JButtons APi and correctly
- use [JButton.setRolloverIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setRolloverIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29) with event from [ButtonModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonModel.html), output should be two [Swing Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)s instead of two `JButton`s added on runtime, and with `ActionListener`s

e.g.

```
JButton.getModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        ButtonModel model = (ButtonModel) e.getSource();
        if (model.isRollover()) {
            //doSomething
        } else if (model.isPressed()) {
           //doSomething
        }  // etc
    }
});
```

---

EDIT

again back

> How would I create it so that when I move my mouse over button A it
>   switches to button B? All I can think of doing is using a mouse
>   listener but I'm wondering if there would be any better way.

- conclusion then first `JButton (button A)` isn't, never will be accesible on users side from `Mouse` or `KeyEvent`s, because both those event will witch that (immediatelly) to `roll_over`,
- then there is only one way, call programatically `JButton.doClick()` from `KeyBinding`s, but still is there question when, how and for why reason ... complicating simple things